# Problems when simulating snakes and ladders game in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to simulate the snakes and ladders game in Python. So far, I have created a module called `iRandom` which contains a dice to be rolled (numbers 1 to 6), and two functions: one of them called `movement` and the other one called `snakes_and_ladders`. [Note: I'm aware that this game can be programmed in many different ways, but I'm doing a programming course and I need to follow some specific instructions].

This is the code that I have so far:

```
import iRandom

def movement(starting_position, distance):
        starting_position = 0
        distance = iRandom.snakes_and_ladders_dice()
        current_space = starting_position + distance
        if current_space > 100:
            current_space = starting_position
        elif current_space == 1:
            current_space = 38
        elif current_space == 4:
            current_space = 14
        elif current_space == 9:
            current_space = 31
        elif current_space == 21:
            current_space = 42
        elif current_space == 28:
            current_space = 84
        elif current_space == 36:
            current_space = 44
        elif current_space == 51:
            current_space = 67
        elif current_space == 71:
            current_space = 91
        elif current_space == 80:
            current_space = 100
        elif current_space == 16:
            current_space = 6
        elif current_space == 47:
            current_space = 26
        elif current_space == 49:
            current_space = 11
        elif current_space == 56:
            current_space = 53
        elif current_space == 62:
            current_space = 19
        elif current_space == 64:
            current_space = 60
        elif current_space == 87:
            current_space = 24
        elif current_space == 93:
            current_space = 73
        elif current_space == 95:
            current_space = 75
        elif current_space == 98:
            current_space = 78
        return current_space

def snakes_and_ladders(must_print):
    current_position = 0
    while current_position < 100:
        number = iRandom.snakes_and_ladders_dice()
        new_position = movement(current_position, number)
        if must_print == TRUE: 
            print("{}\t{}\t{}").format(current_position, number, new_position)
        current_position += new_position


if __name__ == "__main__":
        snakes_and_ladders(must_print)
```

My problem is that when I run `./snakes_and_ladders.py` from the terminal (i.e., the file when this script is stored), I either get syntax error messages or have something printed that is not what I was expecting after correcting the errors.

Some of the things I'm struggling with the most are the following:

- How to integrate the `movement` function into the second function.
- How to 'set' the variable `must_print` (I'm using it because the instructions required it, but I don't really get it... I'm not even sure I'm using it the right way).

Let me know if you can help me figure out what's going on or whether you need any other info!

Comment: Shouldn't there be a loop in `movement`?

Comment: @StephenRauch if you look at the bottom part of my script, you'll see that the first function that starts to run is snakes_and_ladders, and there's already a while loop in this one. So I assume that this function will call movement several times. Am I right?

Comment: My suggestion would be to get some test cases with various `starting_position, distance` combinations and expected return values from `movement`.  Then see if the result is as expected.

Comment: That title is Epic!

Comment: I already did that and I got some weird values: starting_position 0 distance 5 current_position 14 / starting_position 14 distance 3 current_position 2 / starting_position 16 distance 3 current_position 38 ... This is just an example, but it continues until reaching position 79 (which is also weird because the final position should be 100)

Comment: If you are getting weird results, analyze why.  Suggest you start with my first comment to understand the why.